# At what point is this piecewise function continuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

let $$f(z) = \begin{cases}       z & |z|\leq 1 \\
       |z|^{2} & |z|> 1
     \end{cases}\ \text{where}\ z\in \mathbb{C}$$Does anyone could help me ?Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an almost give-away of a hint: $|z|^2$ is real.

Comment: So for |z|>1, it's not continuous, but what about |z|<=1?

Comment: The point is that $f$ is piecewise continuous on the respective domains. I think what the question is asking is at which values of $z$ on the unit circle $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Ok，I got it，thanks